# How to generate form links from image radio buttons to submit button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how I can make it so that the links are generated from the radio images to the next button in my form. I have the original code where when all three questions or radio buttons from each question are check it generates a link and the button becomes clickable. I added images to it and they are clickable but the links are being generated to the next button so that it can be clicked. If you can help please use detailed examples because I'm new to javascript.

Here's the code with the image radio buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/P74tn/1/

The HTML of the document:

```
<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>

<h4>What carrier do you have?</h4>
<div class="radio" id="form">
  <div style="list-style: none;" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="AT&T"><img 
width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="list-style: none;" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="Other">  
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg" />
</div>
    <div style="list-style: none;" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="Unlocked">   
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg" />  
</div>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<h4>What is your phones capicity?</h4>
<div class="radio" id="form">
    <div style="list-style: none;" type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q2" 
value="8GB"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-
image.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="list-style: none;" type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q2"  
value="16GB"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-
image.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<h4>What color is your phone?</h4>
<div class="radio" id="form">
    <div style="list-style: none;" type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q3"   
value="Black"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-
image.jpg" /></div>
    <div style="list-style: none;" type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q3"   
value="White"><img width="50px" height="50px" src="http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-
image.jpg" /></div>
</div>



<br>
<div id=linkDiv>
 <input type=button disabled=disabled value=Next>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your JS fiddle, I'll try to list as many as possible:

- IDs are supposed to be unique, here several divs have the same id "form". You should rename them, such as `id="form_carrier"`, `id="form_color"`, etc.
- You're using a weird mix of jQuery and vanilla JS: either use the jQuery handlers format (i.e. `$('.radio div').on('click', function() {});`) or inline JS (i.e. `onclick="tryToMakeLink();"`). Note that in case of inline JS, the JS code has to be surrounded by quotes.
- The selector to get the result of the choices tries to get `<input>` elements, while in the HTML code, you're using `<div>`; as coded, your selector won't select anything.
- The `:checked` selector only works for `<input>` elements; you can't use it since you're using `<div>` elements. Here, since you set class active to any selected div, you can use the class selector.

Your final selector would look like: `var q1=$('div[name="q1"].active');`

- If a selector doesn't match any element, it doesn't return null, it returns an empty array: `document.querySelector('input[name="q3"]:checked')` will never be null. You should replace your check with: `q1.length === 0`
- You can't use `q1.value`, as value is an attribute of your node. You can use the jQuery function `q1 = q1.attr('value')`
- Rather than changing the innerHTML of your div, you should simply update the input element

I've created a fork of your original fiddle to show you how to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/rCXT5/1/

Comment: Does this not work in opera or IE8? I have both and when I copy the code to my website the buttons aren't clickable, only in Jsfiddle.